# Sharing folder between Ubuntu and Windows

Tags: file-sharing, ubuntu-14.04

How I can share a folder on a Ubuntu (14.04) machine with Windows PCs on the same network?

Thanks and have a nice day.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use **[Samba](https://www.howtoforge.com/samba-server-ubuntu-14.10)** or **[webdav](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-configure-webdav-access-with-apache-on-ubuntu-14-04)**. Both are good ways to handle shares, although Samba is probably the easier way.

Easiest to setup is [Dropbox](https://www.dropbox.com/) or a similar service.